# Creating a full screen div

Tags: html, css

Hi I'm trying to create a nested div that will have the full height of the browser.

I'm using swipe.js, to be able to swipe between three full screen divs. I can get this to work if I define the height of the 'intro' divs but as I want this to work between different screen sizes I was hoping to do this with min-height etc.

```
html {
    /* height: 100%; */
}

body {
    /* height: 100%; */
}

#wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-width: 320px;
    max-width: 1200px;
    /* min-height: 100%; */
    /* height: auto !important; */
    /* height: 100%; */
}

.swipe div {
    margin:0 0px;
    padding:0px 0px;
}

#intro {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;

    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}
```

and the html:

```
<body>

<div id="wrapper">

    <div id='slider' class='swipe'>

    <div>
            <div id="intro" style='display:block; background: url(images/background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;'>
            </div>

            <div id="intro2" style='display:none'>2</div>

            <div id="intro3" style='display:none'>3</div>

        </div>

    </div><!-- #slider -->

</div><!-- #wrapper -->

<script src='swipe.js'></script>
<script>var slider = new Swipe(document.getElementById('slider'));
</script>
</body>
```

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What happens if you do something like: `html, body, #wrapper, #slider, #slider div { width: 100%; height: 100%; }`

Answer (score 2):

See if this what you are trying to achieve:

```
body {
   height: 100%;
    width:100%;
}

#wrapper {
    position:absolute;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-width: 320px;
    max-width: 1200px;
    /* min-height: 100%; */
    /* height: auto !important; */
    height: 100%;
        width:100%;
}

.swipe{
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0 0px;
    padding:0px 0px;
    background-color:red;
}

#intro {
}
```

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TdDuz/3/)**

Comment: Its almost what I'm after however, all of my content will be in the intro div and its not letting me set the height to 100% or auto. I'm trying to have a background image take up all the space. Thanks for trying though.

Comment: Make use of the `Position` as I have used in the style.

Comment: Use the following styles for the Divs that you want to be full screen.
`position:relative;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;`

Comment: I tried to apply it to intro, and the height doesn't seem to work. :(

Comment: This is really good, its what I want but it doesn't seem to work when I insert the swipe.js code. damn it! thanks again for trying

Answer (score 1):

Do as @grc suggests.

```
html, body, #wrapper, #slider, #slider, div { /*You may not want to set this to 'div'*/
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

#wrapper {
    height:100%;
    /*margin: 0 auto;
    min-width: 320px;
    max-width: 1200px;*/ <----- LOSE THIS. This adds nothing to your needs and won't work on IE6 if you want backwards compatibility.
}
```

The important part is not to set a max-width|height to the elements you want, a div will always expand to take the whole horizontal space available so you may want to lose the width property unless you do something like `div{display:inline;}` or something like that. Anyway, if you want to take vertical space, the height:100%; propperty is a must.

Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/TdDuz/14/ (you work in the javascript)

A more complete example jsfiddle.net/TdDuz/15

Comment: @Wex Just edited my answer; do you have documentation that supports what you said?, yes IE6 is a PAIN but cool stuff like jQuery, worries about IE6, why shouldn't we? as long as it does not waste our time nor lose functionality for higher/better browsers.

Comment: Thanks everyone, this is a start as #swipe div is 100% across the screen now , but then it doesn't let me add any formatting styles to any divs within it.

The idea is treat intro divs as pages and have different content on each. But unable to set any height or width properties within that. To make matters worse, I want to set a individual background image on each of those pages. 
Yeah I'm not too concerned about IE6.

Comment: @yani Take a look at the link I added. Maybe you can work from it.

Comment: @Roger - [jQuery 2.0 will not only not support IE6, but it also dropps support for IE7 and IE8](http://blog.jquery.com/2012/06/28/jquery-core-version-1-9-and-beyond/). While I may not agree on their decision to drop IE7 and IE8, [there's more than enough reason for them to drop support for IE6](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_explorer.asp).

Comment: @Wex Good to know that, I hope they are right on "we expect most sites will need it for at least another year or two". Thanks for the links.